# xcode 7 how to suppress warning "overrides a member function but is not marked 'override'"

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, clang

I updated xcode to 7 today. After the update the project I am working on has the warning "overrides a member function but is not marked 'override'". Since our project set "treade warning as error" to true. I got lots of errors.

I double checked "Other Linker Flags" and pretty sure the flag "-Wsuggest-override" is not included.

Since it is a big project I prefer to suppress the warning instead add the keyword "override" everywhere.

Any suggestion for disabling the warning?

Thanks

Comment: You have created an impossible situation.  Either you relax the "treat warnings as errors" or you fix the source code.

Comment: Does the compile provide a option to suppress the warning? That would make sense e.g "-Wno-suggest-override"? The project I am working on has several libs and our app seat on those libs, thousands of virtual functions missing the key word override~~

Comment: Or maybe there is a fantasy tool provided by clang which could automatically add the "override" keyword? I googled, but found nothing

Comment: @RongYang There is a tool, it's called clang-tidy

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to turn off the `-Winconsistent-missing-override` flag which automatically gets added with `-Wall` on recent versions of clang. You can do this by passing the `-Wno-inconsistent-missing-override` flag. [See](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/65fe29acc4077d7d).

Comment: its not helping me m still facing same error, any suggestions what should i do?

Comment: Go into Xcode build settings in "Other C++ Flags" and add "-Wno-inconsistent-missing-override"